# How to make a "n to m" restricted int variant in Scala?

Tags: scala

I'd like to have types s.a. `Int_1to3` or `Uint` in Scala. Preferably, there'd be a general factory method that can provide any such.

It's mostly for self-documentary purposes, but also the values would be checked on arrival (i.e. via 'assert').

I was somewhat surprised not to have found a solution to this during my initial (google) search. The closest I came to is [Unsigned.scala](http://code.google.com/p/funicular/source/browse/trunk/funicular/src/funicular/runtime/Unsigned.scala?r=60), but that's overkill for my needs.

This must be *dead simple*?

Just to give an idea on the usage, something like this would be splendid! :)

```
type Int_1to3= Int_limited( 1 to 3 )
type Uint= Int_limited( _ >= 0 )
```

Comment: you can do that with Shapeless library http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28287612/how-to-require-typesafe-constant-size-array-in-scala

Answer (score 4):

I see two potential solutions:

First you can have a look at [Unboxed Type Tags](http://etorreborre.blogspot.ch/2011/11/practical-uses-for-unboxed-tagged-types.html). They allow to attach a type a compile time without having to box the integer. The compiler will enforce that they are used when needed, but values are checked at runtime.

From the cited article, you could write something like:

```
type Tagged[U] = { type Tag = U }
type @@[T, U] = T with Tagged[U]

trait Positive
trait One2Three

type PositiveInt = Int @@ Positive
type SmallInt = Int @@ One2Three

//Builds a small int
def small(i: Int): SmallInt = {
  require( i > 0 && i < 4, "should be between 1 and 3" )
  i.asInstanceOf[SmallInt]
}

//Builds a positive int
def positive( i: Int): PositiveInt = {
  require( i >= 0, "should be positive" )
  i.asInstanceOf[PositiveInt]
} 

//Example usage in methods
def mul( i: SmallInt, j: PositiveInt ): PositiveInt = positive(i*j)
```

Then in the REPL:

```
scala> mul( small(2), positive(4) )
res1: PositiveInt = 8

scala> mul( small(4), positive(2) ) //RUNTIME ERROR
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: should be between 1 and 3


scala> mul( 2, positive(2) )       //COMPILE TIME ERROR
<console>:16: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(2)
 required: SmallInt
              mul( 2, positive(2) )
                   ^
```

The second solutions may be value classes proposed for Scala 2.10. You can read the [SIP-15](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/value-classes.html) to see how to use them.

Comment: why not using `require(...)` for checking?

Answer (score 2):

A "pattern" you can use here is to declare a sealed type with a private constructor as a wrapper around the underlying value, which is restricted to a single point that it can be validated and instantiated. Eg

```
sealed abstract class Int_1to3(val i:Int)
object Int_1to3 {
  def apply(i:Int):Option[Int_1to3] =
    if (1.to(3).contains(i)) Some(new Int_1to3(i){}) else None
}
```

That way, whenever you end up with an instance of some `x` of type `Int_1to3`, you have a compile-time guarantee that `x.i` will be `1`, `2` or `3`.

Comment: The `range.inclusive` is unnecessary in this case (because it is created with `to`). Furthermore, akauppi said he wanna have an assertion and not an `Option`. Last, I wouldn't say it is a compile-time guarantee. It is true, the programmer knows that only correct values are used, but this is checked at runtime and not at compile time (or would you also call it compile-time guarantee when the code executed at runtime does have a bug and therefore doesn't check for correct values?).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the redundant call to inclusive; I've updated accordingly. Regarding the `Option` return type, this is the "pattern" I use, which can be easily adapted for less type-safe runtime checks if desired. I stand by my comment about compile time guarantees - written this way, there's no way to end up with a compiled program for which you can obtain an instance of `Int_1to3` that has an `i` value of something other than 1, 2 or 3. To get an instance of `Int_1to3`, you must go through the `apply` method (ignoring `null` or reflection hacks).

Comment: Yeah, but what if you have written `1 to 4` instead of `1 to 3`. The compiler can't check this.

Comment: Well, then it wouldn't be "written this way". Of course that would be a logic error; hopefully picked up by a scalacheck property or the like.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have such "low standards", it is enough to do:

```
def safeInt(i: Int, f: Int => Boolean): Int =
  if (f(i)) i else throw new IllegalArgumentException("wrong int")

def int1to3(i: Int) =
  safeInt(i, 1 to 3 contains _)

def uInt(i: Int) =
  safeInt(i, _ >= 0)
```

To have this a a type doesn't make much sense when you do not want to enforce the compiler to keep your code safe. This is possible, but as you said, not for your needs.

Comment: This seems like the first step to a solution, but you didn't complete it because of worrying about the compiler's role. In other languages such as Ada, range-limited integers are normal and are tested at runtime. But it's still useful to define types that describe them because then these provide type-safety: passed as parameters etc.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing like that in the language. The solutions available -- through libraries -- are what you call "overkilL".

Comment: I think his 'overkill' meant a lot more beyond his needs. For example, maybe full arithmetics is beyond his scope.

Answer (score 0):

Saw the [video](https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/6021-scalatest-and-scalactic-3-0) on Scalatest/Scalatric 3.0 yesterday, and in it @Bill-Venners discussed the `PosInt`, `PozInt` types that are very close to what I had been asking in 2012.

He also presented an `OddInt` sample for us to create such value types ourselves.