# How to require typesafe constant-size array in scala?

Tags: scala, shapeless

I need something like this:

```
  def encryptBlock(arr: FixedArray[Size16]) = ???
  val blocks = originalArray.splitFixed[Size16]
  val encrypted = encryptBlock(blocks)
```

In order to be sure that I receive only 128-bit array as input.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Shapeless can do that for seqs:

```
import shapeless._
import nat._
import syntax.sized._

scala> def func(l: Sized[List[Int], _3]) = l
func: (l: shapeless.Sized[List[Int],shapeless.nat._3])shapeless.Sized[List[Int],shapeless.nat._3]

scala> List(1,2,3,4,5,6).grouped(3).map(_.sized(3).get).map(func)
res26: Iterator[shapeless.Sized[List[Int],shapeless.nat._3]] = non-empty iterator

scala> List(1,2,3,4,5,6).grouped(2).map(_.sized(2).get).map(func)
<console>:25: error: type mismatch;
 found   : shapeless.Sized[List[Int],shapeless.nat._3] => shapeless.Sized[List[Int],shapeless.nat._3]
 required: shapeless.Sized[List[Int],shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]]] => ?
              List(1,2,3,4,5,6).grouped(2).map(_.sized(2).get).map(func)
```

Parameter passed to `.size` should be `Literal(Constant(n: Int))`, so you can't pass some variable or expression.

It's also possible convert an Array to some `IndexedSeq` (`.toSeq`), like `Vector` (`.toVector`)

You can also specify some set of accepatable sizes using type disjunction:

```
def func[A <: Nat](l: Sized[List[Int], A])(implicit ev: (_2 with _3) <:< A) = l

func(List(1,2).sized(2).get)
res17: shapeless.Sized[List[Int],shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]]] = shapeless.Sized@3ac1111f

scala> func(List(1,2,3).sized(3).get)
res18: shapeless.Sized[List[Int],shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]]]] = shapeless.Sized@17191095

scala> func(List(1,2,3,4).sized(4).get)
<console>:24: error: Cannot prove that shapeless.nat._2 with shapeless.nat._3 <:< nat_1.N.
              func(List(1,2,3,4).sized(4).get)
                  ^
```

Maximum-N restriction (from @DougC and @Miles Sabin):

```
import ops.nat._
import LT._
scala> def func[N <: Nat](l: Sized[List[Int], N])(implicit ev: N < _3) = l
func: [N <: shapeless.Nat](l: shapeless.Sized[List[Int],N])(implicit ev: shapeless.ops.nat.LT.<[N,shapeless.nat._3])shapeless.Sized[List[Int],N]

scala> func(List(1,2).sized(2).get)
res25: shapeless.Sized[List[Int],shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]]] = shapeless.Sized@3ac1111f

scala> func(List(1).sized(1).get)
res26: shapeless.Sized[List[Int],shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]] = shapeless.Sized@73f49b57

scala> func(List(1,2,3).sized(3).get)
<console>:30: error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev: shapeless.ops.nat.LT[nat_1.N,shapeless.nat._3]
              func(List(1,2,3).sized(3).get)
                  ^
```

Comment: Is it possible to use shapeless to specify a seq that has a maximum size, rather than a fixed size?

Comment: Thanks. in fact, on gitter, Miles provided this as a building block `def frob[N <: Nat](l: Sized[N])(implicit ev: LT[N, _3]) ... ` that, I think, points to a way to do what I'm after. The compiler will generate the implicit value for `ev` at the call sites. I'm pretty sure I can use that to build up a a `FiniteSeq[T, N :< Nat]` class or similar.

Comment: LessThan, cool, i'll add it to my answer. I suppose it's in `ops.nat` package

Comment: Yep. Along with some other very interesting type classes.