# Scala how to let scala commit to the specified type bounds

Tags: scala, types

I create a hierarchy of types, `S_3 <: S_2 <: S_1 <: S_0 <: Selector`, which I want to use to select a field from a data structure, while giving the guarantee, that the user is not asking for a field, which doesn't exist.

E.g. if `_1, _2 and _3` are constructors for the types `S_1, S_2 and S_3`, then I intent the following:

```
 val x : (Int, String) = .. 
 x(_0) : TypeError 
 x(_1) : Int 
 x(_2) : String 
 x(_3) :  TypeError!
```

My first approach was to constrain the type as follow:

```
  implicit class Bla2[+A,+B](val x : (A,B)) {
         def apply[N >: S_2 <: S_1](i : N) : Any = {
           i match {
              case 1 => x._1 
              case 2  => x._2 
          }
    }
```

Where the key information is: `N >: S_2 <: S_1`. I expected that scala would infer from the provided value `x: N`, if the type is allowed or not. However that doesn't happen, precisely.

If I compile the following (where _3 is a constructor for S_3):

```
 val x : (Int, String) = (1, "hello")
 x(_3)
```

It will happily compile.

For the _0 it works fine.

I can see the reason for this. Because S_3 <: S_2, it is safe to generalize the type to S_2. Scala actually does this, but now  the constraints on the type are fulfilled.

For S_0 it work. Because S_0 >: S_2 <: S_1 cannot be true and there is no safe way to convert an S_0 to an S_1.

I need a way to force scala to not generalize the type and keep it as specific as possible. How can I achieve this?

I know it is possible by using type encoded Naturals or some other type with a richer structure, but I would like to keep the code as simple as possible. I just need an ordering.

The full code is below (the whole tuple thing is just for testing purposes):

```
object Main extends App {
      sealed trait Selector {
           def unapply() : Int  
      }
      sealed class S_0 extends Selector {
           def unapply() : Int = 0
      }
      sealed class S_1 extends S_0 {
          override def unapply() : Int = 1 
      }
      sealed class S_2 extends S_1 {
          override def unapply() : Int = 2 
      }
      sealed class S_3 extends S_2 {
          override def unapply() : Int = 3 
      }

     def _0 = new S_0
     def _1 = new S_1
     def _2 = new S_2
     def _3 = new S_3


    implicit class Bla2[+A,+B](val x : (A,B)) {
         def apply[N >: S_2 <: S_1](i : N) : Any = {
           i match {
              case 1 => x._1 
              case 2  => x._2 
          }
    }
 }

 println("hello world")
 val b = (1,2)
 b[S_1](_1)
 b[S_2](_2)
 //  this won't compile 
 //   b[S_3](_3)
 //  but this will
 b(_3)
 }
```

EDIT: The problem lies in the inference of the types. If the type is explicitly specified as in: `b[S_3](_3)` it won't compile.

Comment: maybe, it's easier to use shapeless `Nat` type: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28287612/how-to-require-typesafe-constant-size-array-in-scala

Comment: @dk14 That works indeed , but I was curious if there is a way to force the type inference to be more specific. If type is specified by hand `b[S_3](_3)` the compiler correctly rejects the statement.  And sometimes you don't want to pull in a whole library for just one feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do "more/less-than-or-equals" with implicit + contravariance:

```
trait _4
trait _3 extends _4
trait _2 extends _3
trait _1 extends _2
trait _0 extends _1

trait >:>[A, -B] //more-than or equals

object Laws {
  implicit def mte[A] = new >:>[A,A]{}//00, 11, 22, 33...contravariance will also add 23, 24, 34 etc. 
}


import Laws._

//the type here is going to be bound (inclusive) between 3 and 2
def a[T <: _3](a: T)(implicit ev: T >:> _2) = a
```

Results:

```
scala> a(new _2{})
res29: _2 = $anon$1@13a37e2a

scala> a(new _3{})
res26: _3 = $anon$1@779dfe55

scala> a(new _4{})
<console>:27: error: inferred type arguments [_4] do not conform to method a's type parameter bounds [T <: _3]
              a(new _4{})
              ^
<console>:27: error: type mismatch;
 found   : _4
 required: T
              a(new _4{})
                ^
<console>:27: error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev: >:>[T,_2]
              a(new _4{})
               ^

scala> a(new _1{})
<console>:27: error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev: >:>[_1,_2]
              a(new _1{})
               ^
```

Alternatively, you could just use Shapeless: [How to require typesafe constant-size array in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28287612/how-to-require-typesafe-constant-size-array-in-scala)

**UPDATE**:

Here's the way to do it for an opposite type-hierarchy:

```
trait _0
trait _1 extends _0
trait _2 extends _1
trait _3 extends _2
trait _4 extends _3
trait _5 extends _4

import annotation.implicitNotFound

@implicitNotFound("Can’t prove ${A} <= ${B}")
trait <=[A, -B] //less-than or equals

object Laws {

  @implicitNotFound("Can’t prove ${A} >= ${B}")
  type >=[A,B] = <:<[A,B]

  implicit def lte[A] = new <=[A,A]{}//00, 11, 22, 33...contravariance will also add 23, 24, 34 etc. 
}


import Laws._
def a[T](a: T)(implicit ev1: T >= _2, ev2: T <= _3) = a
```

Comment: That'is a neat trick. MTE almost has the same type as Leib, but because of subtyping it will allow type inference to act like more than or equal. Thanks!

The only thing, which is a shame, is that the type is effectively closed. We cannot higher numbers than _4, but for that I probably better go to type encoded Naturals.

Comment: @EdgarKlerks we actually can - see my update. Noice, isn't it?

Comment: btw, `Leibniz`-like `[+A, -B]` (with additional covariance on `A`) also works