# Array to Tuple in Spark with many input variables

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, tuples

Lets say I am importing a flat file from HDFS into spark using something like the following:

```
val data = sc.textFile("hdfs://name_of_file.tsv").map(_.split('\t'))
```

This will produce an `Array[Array[String]]`.  If I wanted an array of tuples I could do as referenced in this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585549/how-to-convert-an-array-to-a-tuple) and map the elements to a tuple.

```
val dataToTuple = data.map{ case Array(x,y) => (x,y) }
```

But what if my input data has say, 100 columns?  Is there a way in scala using some sort of wildcard to say

```
val dataToTuple = data.map{ case Array(x,y, ... ) => (x,y, ...) }
```

without having to write out 100 variable to match on?

I tried doing something like

```
val dataToTuple = data.map{ case Array(_) => (_) }
```

but that didn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: Why would you want a tuple with 100 elements? Just use the array that `split` produces?

Comment: You can create a `Row` instead of a `Tuple`

Comment: if you really need that - you can use Shapeless library: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19901310/1809978, but be aware that maximum size of tuple is limited in scala to 22 (last time I was checking it) + I believe, you still have to specify type per column. Besides, it might not be what you actually need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data-columns are homogenous (like `Array` of `String`s) - tuple may not be a best solution to improve type-safety. All you can do is to fix the size of your array using sized list from Shapeless library:

[How to require typesafe constant-size array in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28287612/how-to-require-typesafe-constant-size-array-in-scala)

This is a right approach if your column's are unnamed. For instance, your row might be a representation of a vector in Euclidean space.

Otherwise (named columns, maybe different types), it's better to model it with a case class, but be aware of [size restriction](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/7910). This might help you to quickly map array (or its parts) to ADT: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19901310/1809978